# flex3 property from another class is null

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have an application which has a 'user.as' class and I have a popup which displays products details.  I want to add a 'market' property to this popup but it's not working. here is the code:

#### User.as:

```
package com.brb.domain
{

[RemoteClass(alias="com.brb.user.userIBO")]
[Table(name="User")]
[Bindable]
public class User
{
    /**
     * Id of the user.
     */
    [Id(strategy="assigned")]
    public var UserID: Number;
    
    public var market: String;
    
    public var isAuthenticated: Boolean;
    
    public function User()
    {
        super();
    }
}
```

}

I then have an `Product.mxml` class which displays the product details in a popup:

```
import com.brb.domain.Product;
import com.brb.domain.User;

...
[Bindable]
private var _product: Product;
[Bindable]
private var _currentUser: User;

public function set product( value: Product ): void
        {
this._product = value;
mySrc ="file:///C|/MultimediaSync/market_"+this.market.toString()+"/pictures/"+imageName;   
trace(this._currentUser.market.toString());
...
```

}

The above is returning:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

My question is how can I access properties from `User.as class` in another function like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex is an Object Oriented language. What this means is that (in most cases, excluding things called 'statics') you need an *instance* of an *object* to access its characteristics.

In this case, 'User' is your object, as defined in User.as, and you need an *instance* of it, by calling

```
_currentUser = new User();
```

somewhere in your MXML, before you try to reference `_currentUser.market`. This `new User()` syntax is referred to as instantiating an object, or creating an instance. Afterwards, `_currentUser` holds a reference to that instance of the object, which has a `_market` property you can access.

Comment: That's right, it is not throwing an error but it's null...not sure why

Comment: You've created a new User, but unless you do something like  `_currentUser.market = 'value';`, the value of the market property *is* null.

Comment: true...this value should be returned from a database...i guess I need to do this in     user.as ...like a loop?

Comment: Making a database call in flex is a hassle, and if you need assistance with that you should ask a new question. By '...like a loop?' I assume you mean you're getting a collection of Users from the DB. In that case, you would make the DB call outside of User.as, and in that place, you would create a new User() for each returned row, set thatuser.market, thatuser.stsUserID, thatuser.isAuthenticated from the data in that row, and put them in some ArrayCollection or other collection. That part would happen in a loop, yes.

Comment: That's helpful - thanks.  I had to edit the initial post code for confidentiality but it does not change anything on the answers.